# Placeholder for input type date (only when no value entered)

Tags: html, jquery, date, input, placeholder

I am trying to set a placeholder for the input type date.

What I want:
If the value has not been inputted, or it remains default (like dd/mm/yyyy), then the placeholder is showing. If there is a date inserted, then no placeholder is shown.

What I have:
The placeholder is only showing before focusing on the element, after that it just goes away forever, even if no values are typed into the date picker.

```js
$( ".dateInput" ).focus(function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('value') != '' ) {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
    $(this).css('text-align', 'left');
    console.log('no place');
  } else {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "Date of Birth*");
    $(this).css('text-align', 'right');
    console.log('place');
  }
});
```

```css
.loanInput {
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #008e39;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type=date] {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="date"]:before {
  color: #999;
  content: attr(placeholder) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" class="loanInput dateInput" required placeholder="Date of Birth*">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to use `change` event, in place of `focus`. By using `change`, the changes will take place only when input date would be valid :)

```js
$( ".dateInput" ).change(function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('value') != '' ) {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "").css('text-align', 'left');
    console.log('no place');
  } else {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "Date of Birth*").css('text-align', 'right');
    console.log('place');
  }
});
```

```css
.loanInput {
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #008e39;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type=date] {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="date"]:before {
  color: #999;
  content: attr(placeholder) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" class="loanInput dateInput" required placeholder="Date of Birth*">
```

Comment: Yep, I'm happy with that!

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer as correct. Besides that, in case you need any explanation, let me know. Happy coding :)